# Jquery DataTable Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I used Jquery datatable in my webpage. Also I used custom filter for the grid. Here is the below code for custom filter.

**Code**

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable();

jQuery('#myDataTable_filter').find("input").keyup(function () {
    var Input = $(this).val();
    oTable.fnFilter('^' + Input, null, true, null);
    $('#myDataTable_filter').find("input").val(Input);
});
```

The above code works fine for all the cases but not for searching (A*STAR). Its not selecting the correct search results. Anybody can help me sort out the issue.

Comment: Can you try oTable.fnFilter('^' + Input.replace('*', ' \ *'), null, true, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution not working for `A*STAR` because when you are filtering it here:

```
oTable.fnFilter('^' + Input, null, true, null);
```

regex is generating `^A*STAR` but while `*` is meta character correct regex should escaped by `\` so regex should be `^A\*STAR`.

You can see [**REGEX MetaCharacter**](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php)

---

Updated Code added `^` meta character

```
var Input = $(this).val().replace(/([&\/\\#,\^+()$~%.'":*?<>{}])/g,"\\$1");//this is will add prefix \ to meta character
oTable.fnFilter('^' + Input, null, true, null);
```

Comment: How about searching for the word `A^STAR` ?? As the above regex is not working while searching for `A^Start`.

Comment: What exact you want to match??

Comment: In my grid the value `A^Star Hotels in Singapore` is there. The regex should result the above value if i search with the key word `A^Star`. But it does not return any value.

Comment: Need one more help. When I search for the string `(CHS)`, there is no changes in the filtered records until I complete typing `(CHS)`. Say, There are 10 records in the grid. Out of which only one record matches the string `(CHS)`. But when type in `(` or `(CHS` characters no change in the grid. When I complete with `(CHS)` then it shows one record nicely. Please help.